# Remove duplicate rows from multiple criteria using SQL queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, window-functions, sql-delete

I have a table with columns `Machine`, `Product` and `Sources`:

| Machine | Product | Sources |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M3 | H | cmdd6 |
| M3 | H | 91 |
| M3 | H | cmdd3 |
| M4 | I | cmdd7 |
| M4 | J | cmdd7 |
| M4 | B | 827 |
| M4 | B | cmdd7 |

In the above table where `Machine` is M3 the product is same but the `Sources` column has multiple intake. So the requirement is to remove the duplicate rows where `Sources` should always be 'cmdd' in ascending order.

For example if there is duplicate with product and sources are different i.e 'cmdd6' or 'cmdd3', then duplicate row should be removed and values would remain with sources 'cmdd3'.

Below is the result table would to like to achieve

| Machine | Product | Sources |
| --- | --- | --- |
| M3 | H | cmdd3 |
| M4 | I | cmdd7 |
| M4 | J | cmdd7 |
| M4 | B | cmdd7 |

Below is the query which I tried to remove duplicates on the values of count >1.

```
WITH CTE(Machine, Product,Sources, duplicatecount) AS 
(
    SELECT 
        Machine, Product, Sources, 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Machine, Product
                           ORDER BY Machine, Sources) AS DuplicateCount
    FROM 
        Concatcleanup 
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE duplicatecount > 1
```

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Do you really want to `DELETE` the other rows? That seems bad. A more typical request is a SELECT query that returns the results you care about while leaving the base data intact.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn thank you for highlighting. Sure I’ll do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one extra crafted field inside the `ORDER BY` clause `ROW_NUMBER` window function, to pull "*cmdd%*"-like values above all the others.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
               PARTITION BY Machine, Product
               ORDER BY CASE WHEN Sources NOT LIKE 'cmdd%' THEN 1 END,
                        Sources
           ) AS DuplicateCount                 
    FROM Concatcleanup
)
DELETE FROM cte
WHERE DuplicateCount > 1;
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/fAoy-ONP).

---

If you want to avoid the deletion, you can use the notation `SELECT ... INTO <new_table> FROM ...` and use the code for the cte:

```
SELECT Machine, Product, Sources,  
       ROW_NUMBER() OVER(
           PARTITION BY Machine, Product
           ORDER BY CASE WHEN Sources NOT LIKE 'cmdd%' THEN 1 END,
                    Sources
       ) AS DuplicateCount
INTO newtab
FROM Concatcleanup;
```

Check the demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/MG1mLKj9).

Comment: Thank you for your code. The code works fine. As mentioned by Joel Coehoorn, it would be very ineffective if we would delete the main data. So I require your help with minor changes if we could save the result data into another table, without deleting the main data.